# Get position of an object after rotation with three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

i have a object with a position and i apply a rotation on it. I would like to get the position of this object after the rotation to move my camera on this position and set the lookAt vector on this position.

How to do that?

thx!

Comment: Could you share the specific code you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
cameraPosition.getPositionFromMatrix(object.worldMatrix);
```

**cameraPosition** now holds the position of **object** with the rotation applied.